# Checking if the data from Firebase is equal to if else?

Tags: java, android, firebase, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database

If the data from Firebase is the same, I want a new page to be opened, but in the written code, it checks the text in the xml. I just want If Else to work if the data from the firebase is the same.

I can't find where I went wrong, I've just started, I'm a beginner.
If text11 and text22 are equal, the page should be opened.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text11;
    TextView text22;
    View view;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text11 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text22 = findViewById(R.id.text2);


        String veri1 = text11.getText().toString();
        String veri2 = text22.getText().toString();

        if(veri1.equals(veri2)) {
            System.out.println("firebase data equal");
        }else {
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sec);
            System.out.println("firebase data not equal");
        }

        //Firebase mesajı
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("pass1");


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                String m=snapshot .getValue(String.class);
                text11.setText(m);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



        DatabaseReference myReff = database.getReference("pass2");
        myReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                String m=snapshot .getValue(String.class);
                text22.setText(m);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

XML Code ;

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.603" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Any code that needs the data from Firebase needs to be *inside* the `onDataChange` that gets called when that data has been loaded. Since you need two pieces of data from the database, you need to nest those calls and then perform the check inside the inner `onDataChange`.

In code that'd be something like this:

```
// 1. Start loading first value
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // 2. Got first value

        String m=snapshot .getValue(String.class);
        text11.setText(m);

        // 3. Start loading second value
        DatabaseReference myReff = database.getReference("pass2");
        myReff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // 4. Got second value

                String m=snapshot .getValue(String.class);
                text22.setText(m);

                // 5. Compare values
                String veri1 = text11.getText().toString();
                String veri2 = text22.getText().toString();

                if(veri1.equals(veri2)) {
                    System.out.println("firebase data equal");
                }else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sec);
                    System.out.println("firebase data not equal");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
            }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
    }
});
```

I've indicated the flow through this code in numbered comments.